# Is it possible to meet my travel partner in terminal 2E at CDG prior to clearing immigration?

Tags: france, cdg

We are both arriving from the US, about half an hour apart from each other, on nonstop Delta/Air France flights to CDG. Both flights arrive at terminal 2E.

Is it possible for us to meet somewhere in 2E prior to clearing passport control and customs?

I haven't flown into CDG in a long time, so I don't know if we'll deplane into a sterile area where you are shunted to passport control and/or security rescreening immediately, or if we'll arrive into the airside area and be able to wander around (and find the later arriving person's arrival gate).

I am aware there is a meeting point in 2E landside, and if we have to meet there after clearing immigration and customs individually it is completely fine. But it's nice to wait with someone in those long passport control lines, especially as we are non-EU/EEA citizens.

Comment: If you wait too long for your friend and Paris is your destination, then you may need to hunt down bags as they won't stay on the belt for long.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you get off the plane you arrive in an area that has big LCD screens and sign boards that point you towards transfer, immigration, etc, as well as some AF kiosks, I think, to get your next boarding pass, if you're transferring on AF. You could, probably, loiter here for a while, but if I were you, I'd cross immigration and wait out at the luggage belts. Pick up your luggage, then find out where your friend's luggage will be sent, and wait there.

If you leave your luggage unattended too long, no telling what's going to happen to it...

Comment: Question answered directly (what kind of environment you deplane into), as well as the point about luggage which I hadn't even considered!